# login fails and returns to login screen

Tags: login, power-management

I run Ubuntu 10.04 inside VMware on a windows host. <del>After a power outage</del>  I can no longer log into Ubuntu. I get to the login screen, which mysteriously also changed its color theme from the standard ubuntu theme to some bluish theme. When I type in my password. It seems to do something, the screen turns black a cursor appears for a second but then it returns to the login screen. In the upper right corner appears a error message:

> INSTALL PROBLEM! The configuration defaults for GNOME Power Manager have not been installed correctly. Please contact your computer administrator.

Just to be clear, if I type in the wrong password, I get the regular `Authentication failure` error. Any ideas of what's going on? How could I save the system?

Comment: can you test login in tty (Ctrl+Alt+F1)?

Comment: @Stefano: yep, that worked

Comment: Can you select a different desktop before giving your password?

Comment: Okay, I just realized that my disk is almost completely full and my problem might not be related to the power outage. I will update my question when I have taken care of it.

Comment: rm -rfv is your friend. It will recursively do the job. Handle it with care!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed it. Hope this will also help others. Forget about the power outage, completely unrelated. I was downloading and building lots of files over night and the disk filled up to its limts. The steps I took to fix it:

On login screen:

```
Ctrl+Alt+F1 //(thanks Stefano)
```

commands I used:

- to check the disk usage: `df -h`
- to check directory size: `du -h /home/lucas/some_gigantic_directory`
- remove a gigantic directory: `rm -vR /home/lucas/some_gigantic_directory`
- and reboot: `sudo reboot`